# on_message function repeating, Discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a bot that, when it detects you are using a banned word, it will delete your message. Simple enough but, when I do that. The on_message function is repeating itself. I don't know why but I hope you can answer my question

```
@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    contents = msg.content.split(" ")
    for word in contents:
        if word.lower() in chat_filter: #ChatFilter is a list of words that cannot be used
            try:
                await msg.delete()
                await msg.channel.send("**YOU ARE NOT ALLOWED TO USE THIS WORD!!!**")
            except discord.errors.NotFound:
                return
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what it means `repeats itself` ?

Comment: @reportgunner well, I was following a youtube video. For him when he did the code, it did it once for him. I copied his code and it keeps repeating itself. I think its the difference with the versions and stuff

Comment: I asked since I have no idea if you mean "repeats itself" as in "runs in a loop indefinitely" or "messages are duplicated" (i.e. there are two responses for each message) or "messages multiply exponentially".

Comment: @reportgunner yes. The messages are repeating itself even though I don't want it to happen. Any solution? I'll give you the link to the video to show you what I mean https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2b1JUwEF3o

Comment: Is one of the words in `chat_filter` also in the message?  You can add a check to ignore your own messages: `if msg.author == client.user: return`

Comment: @Patrick Haugh What do you mean by **is one of the words in chat_filter also in the message**. The chat_filter is a list of strings that you cannot use on a message. For example a swear word is in the chat_filter, if a user says that swear word the bot will delete it

Comment: @TheBigBro122 So if "allowed" was in `chat_filter`, then the bot would respond to itself forever. It sounds like that's no the case.  If you have a bot with just this event, and no other functionality, do you still see the multiple response behaviour?

Comment: @Patrick Haugh No, the bot will not respond to itself forever because it will not say "allowed" if it was in `chat_filter` it will just delete the message and tell a different sentence. By really looking up to my problem, I discovered another problem, instead of repeating, the messages in the `on_message` function is doubling up, do you know what is causing my problem

Comment: @TheBigBro122 What other code do you have that could be interacting with your `on_message`?  Are you also using `add_listener` or maybe have a cog with a similar `on_message` event?

Comment: @Patrick Haugh I'm the only one who is interacting with the `on_message` function. And no, I don't use `add_listener` or cogs

Answer (score 1):

You're looping over each word of the message and sending a response for each of those words that are also in `chat_filter`.  Instead, send a single message if any of the words are in the banned list:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    contents = msg.content.split(" ")
    if any(word in chat_filter for word in contents):
        try:
            await msg.delete()
            await msg.channel.send("**YOU ARE NOT ALLOWED TO USE THIS WORD!!!**")
        except discord.errors.NotFound:
            return
```

Comment: That is just doing the same thing too. This is the video that I am trying to copy  youtube.com/watch?v=-2b1JUwEF3o

Comment: hello, its me again. I just found a solution. I don't wanna tell it because of how dumb it was. Just wanna thank you for helping me find the solution